# Cloud Kit - Synching image

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I'm currently sharing data between devices using core data and cloud kit.

Currently I have a "Picture" entity which stores the filename, the date it was added and a relation to another entity.

The details in core data successfully syncs, how would I go about syncing the image file.
The file is saved in the documents folder and I can get its file path using

```
let imagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(imageName)
```

Research seems to show I need to use CKAsset to upload/download the file but how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by saving the image as data into core data, can then convert it back to an image when displaying